# Is there a way to change the Save File Prompt?

Tags: excel, office365

I love the old way Excel and other office programs used to prompt if you didnt save before closing a file, like this:

[image]

But now I get this:

[image]

Ive tried to uninstall OneDrive thinking that was it, but it didnt work.
Does anyone have the solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: 
At File | Options | Save, select "Don't show the Backstage when opening or saving files" and click OK.